# How can i create a SelectListItem() with Int Value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the folloiwng code inside my asp.net mvc action method:-

```
var CustomerData = customerlist.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = m.SDOrganization.NAME,
                Value = m.SDOrganization.ORG_ID.ToString(),

            });
```

currently if i remove the ToString() from the ORG_ID , i will get an error that "can not explicitly convert long to string". so it seems that i have to define both the value and the text for the SelectListItem as strings. but since the SelectListItem should hold long , so is there a way to pass the values of the SelectListItem as long instead of strings?

Comment: Read up on the model binder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx and it will help you understand why you don't need to worry about this too much

Comment: but in this way of i have an empty string in the Value for the SelectListItem,, how it will be bind using the model binder ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ...so is there a way to pass the values of the SelectListItem as long instead of strings?

No. And it doesn't make any sense to do so as when it is rendered, it's just HTML which has no concept of `long`.

If we have the action

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>
    {
        { 1, "One" },
        { 2, "Two" },
        { 3, "Three" }
    };

    ViewBag.SelectList = new SelectList(dictionary, "Key", "Value");

    return this.View();
}
```

and the following view "Test.cshtml":

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownList("id", ((SelectList)ViewBag.SelectList), "All")
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />
}
```

The generated HTML is

```
<form action="/home/test" method="post">
  <select id="id" name="id">
    <option value="">All</option>
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>    
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

and when we post to this action, text of your number is effectively parsed back into your desired type by the Model Binder

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(int? id)
{
    var selectedValue = id.HasValue ? id.ToString() : "All";

    return Content(String.Format("You selected '{0}'", selectedValue));
}
```

And the above works as you might expect.

Comment: but if i want to have an option inside my selectListItem such as "All" , where its value should be null ,,, so what is the best way to do o ?

Comment: Just use an empty string for that value and have it as a nullable integer in the action you post to.

Comment: so you mean if i define an empty string as the selectlistitem value, then the model binder will map the empty string as a null for a Nullable<int> variable ?